# How to reference subquery in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have a SQL query (T-SQL) in which I have a subquery in the `SELECT` statement.

Here is a reduced version:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id,
    (SELECT
        jobs_without_price.id
    FROM
        st_job jobs_without_price
    WHERE
        jobs_without_price.person_id = p.id
    AND
        jobs_without_price.price IS NULL
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('jobs')) AS JobsWithoutPrice
FROM
    st_person p
WHERE
    JobsWithoutPrice IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    p.id
```

The problem is that SSMS tells me

> Invalid column name 'JobsWithoutPrice'.

This is almost certainly because SQL doesn't allow aliases in `WHERE` clauses, but how else can I use the result of this subquery to filter the results?

[The full query has more table joins and much more in the `SELECT` statement, all of which pertains to a single *person* record, whereas the subquery reports back multiple records, which is why it's in a subquery.]

Comment: You need to look at a column, not the entire query. So JobsWithoutPrice.id ID NOT NULL

Comment: where table is null is invalid syntax.  Where table.column is null is valid.

Comment: Trying `JobsWithoutPrice.id IS NOT NULL` results in the error "The multi-part identifier "JobsWithoutPrice.id" could not be bound.", whether or not I have the `FOR XML` modifier.

Comment: `Jobswithoutprice.id` is not a valid field when referenced from the outer query. My answer below should help you understand why. You could just go with `id IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to to that by simply moving the `sub-query` in `CROSS APPLY` operator. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id
   ,newXML
FROM
    st_person p
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        jobs_without_price.id AS JobsWithoutPrice
    FROM
        st_job jobs_without_price
    WHERE
        jobs_without_price.person_id = p.id
    AND
        jobs_without_price.price IS NULL
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('jobs')
) AS DS (newXML)
--WHERE
--    newXML IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    p.id;
```

Note, that I have commented the last `WHERE` clause. We should in need of it, as `CROSS APPLY` will return the rows from the left part who a match of a row(s) in the right part (like `INNER JOIN`). You can try `OUTER APPLY` for getting all rows from the left part of the operator (like `LEFT JOIN`).

You are allowed to use the columns returned by the `APPLY` operator in every clause (`SELECT`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `HAVING`, `GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 0):

The scope of table aliases when used in a subquery or common table expression (CTE) is limited to that subquery. They cannot be referenced by an outer query. Consider the following query:

```
declare @table table (id int identity, col1 varchar(10));
insert @table(col1) values ('aaa'),('bbb'),('ccc');

select * 
from 
( 
  -- I can reference table aliases for this query in here
  select sub1.id, sub1.col1, sub2.x
  from @table sub1
  join (select 'xxx' as x) sub2 on sub1.col1 <> sub2.x
  where sub2.x is not null
) innerQuery
where innerQuery.col1 is not null -- this is ok
--where sub1.col1 is not null     -- this will fail
```

Note my comments. Here we have and inner and outer query. The inner query one lives between the brackets, the outer query references the inner query. My inner query has two column aliases: sub1 and sub2. I can reference sub1 or sub2 anywhere inside the two parentheses. Sub1 and sub2 are not valid outside of those parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS id,
    -- sum(a), max(b), min(c) <--- what you want from JobsWithoutPrice table
FROM st_person p inner join (
    (SELECT jobs_without_price.id, -- jobs_without_price.a, jobs_without_price.b, jobs_without_price.c
    FROM st_job jobs_without_price
    WHERE jobs_without_price.price IS NULL
    FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('jobs')) AS JobsWithoutPrice
) on (jobs_without_price.person_id = p.id)
GROUP BY p.id
```